# Move .mp3 files to the same directory in another folder

Tags: batch-file, nas

I have recently put plex onto my nas running freenas. I have setup a music library to my main folder for music and plex has found my mp3 and flac files which i didn't want it to do. Is there a way i can move all mp3 files to another location with one command?

I would like this to happen;
Move mp3 files from /Music/ to /mp3Music/ for every single artist which i have a folder for.

I am using windows and can use CMD for commands or batch files.

UPDATE:
I have the following command `for /R %i in (*.MP3) do move "%i" "Y:/"` it copied the files into the directory but didn't put them into the folders so it looks like the original.

Comment: You are probably looking for the `for` loop (type `for /?` in a new command prompt window and read the help very carefully)...

Comment: i don't know much about commands at all could you give me a command that i could test out. I can change the paths if you could just do the command.

Comment: Start with the help information that aschipfl told you about. Then try writing something. Maybe make a test directory with just a few fake files in it to test it out. If it doesn't work, edit your question with what you tried and someone can help you fix it.

Comment: I have tried this `for /R %i in (*.MP3) do move "%i" "Y:/"` and it copied the files but didn't put them into the folders they were in before. I looked through the help and i couldn't find anything which i thought would help me.

Comment: Why do you not move the files with Windows Explorer as it looks like you need to do this only once?

Comment: I have 434 folders that i would have to go into and manually move every mp3 files to the correct location in another folder. I figured it would be easier to use a command.

Comment: In your attempt you are using `/` as path separator (`Y:/`), but you should always use the backspash in Windows/batch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a command prompt window run the following command line:

```
for /R %I in (*.mp3) do md "Y:%~pI" 2>nul & move "%I" "Y:%~pnxI"
```

Or create a batch file with following lines and execute it:

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in (*.mp3) do (
    md "Y:%%~pI" 2>nul
    move "%%I" "Y:%%~pnxI"
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`

And for an explanation of operator `&` read answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/).

`2>nul` used to redirect error messages output by command `md` to handle **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress them is explained in the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
copy *.mp3 y:
del *.mp3
```

I think that is much easier than doing this in a for loop

Or just use

```
move *.mp3 y:
```

Comment: The goal was to move all MP3 files from entire directory tree of current directory with the directory structure to drive Y: and not just moving all MP3 files in current directory on current drive to current directory on drive Y: as your commands do.